# Can I use two keys from one of the data sets and one key from another dataset when I merge two data sets?

Tags: pandas

I would like to have an index for countries. But I have two columns of country names. One column is for the origin of the FDI and the other one is for the destination of the FDI.

| origin | destination | FDI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | UK | 120 |
| ITA | US | 90 |
| TR | SPA | 40 |

This is the other data set I will use.

| Country | Index |
| --- | --- |
| ITA | 0 |
| UK | 1 |
| TR | 0 |
| SPA | 1 |

Should I merge the latest data set two times with the first one changing the key for each time. Or there is a better way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected output is unclear, but you can [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) as many columns as you want:

```
mapper = df2.set_index('Country')['Index']

df1[['new_origin', 'new_destination']] = (df1[['origin', 'destination']]
                                          .apply(lambda s: s.map(mapper))
                                          )
```

Or with [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
out = df1.join(df1.drop(columns='FDI')
                  .apply(lambda s: s.map(mapper))
                  .add_prefix('new_'))
```

output:

```
  origin destination  FDI  new_origin  new_destination
0     US          UK  120         NaN              1.0
1    ITA          US   90         0.0              NaN
2     TR         SPA   40         0.0              1.0
```

Comment: Amazing! new_origin and new_destination in this case are the indices, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Yes; you can use `.add_suffix('_index')` to have `origin_index`/`destination_index` instead ;)